# PHP Pagination previous button/link

Tags: php, pagination

I have a fully working pagination system obtained from W£Schools website. I customized it and it works without fault.

I was wondering if there is an easy way of adding a 'previous' link at the start of the list. Tried doing it by `-1` on the current page but it broke the rest of the pagination.

Here is my current working code:

```
$adjacents = "2";

$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page); 
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page; 

$prev = $page - 1; 
$next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;

$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{ 
$pagination .= "<ul>";
//$pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) { 
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
    {
        if ($counter == $page)
        $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
        else
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
    }
}
elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
    if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page) {
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='active'>$counter</a></li>";
            } else {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
            }
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>"; 
    }
    elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page) {
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='active'>$counter</a></li>";
            } else {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
            }
        }
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>";                                   
    } else {
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
        $pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page) {
                $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
            } else {
                $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
            }
        }
    }
    if ($page < $counter - 1) {
    $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$next'>Next</a></li>";
    // $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
    }else{
    //$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
    // $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
    }
    $pagination.= "</ul>\n"; 
} 
return $pagination;
} 

$page=1;//Default page
$limit=26;//Records per page
$start=0;//starts displaying records from 0
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!=''){
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start=($page-1)*$limit;
```

Comment: Yes. There is always a way: you can program whatever behavior you wish. However, questions "Please fix my code for me" considered to be offtopic on this site.

Comment: I'm not saying please fix my code. I'm saying I'm not advanced enough to add this feature could some at least point me in the right direction without giving me code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `prev` variable there present. You just need to add it.

```
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$prev'>Prev</a></li>";
```

Place it as your first `li` element. A word of waring, you will need an `if` statement otherwise it will break when you go previous when on page `1`

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. I didn't even notice the prev variable. It does break at page one but i know you have already stated this. I will disable it's ability based on an if statement. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason i went straight to the problem is because I have used this script myself on many occasions. I'm not that advanced at php either, still learning.